# how to distinguish function names in C++ if I have same function name but one is C++ and another is C

Tags: c++, c

suppose I have a class with one of the method member name is close,
and inside the class, I'm using C function  to open and close file

thus, I will have two completely different function with the same name, but one is C and another is C++.

Thus, when I call close, seems compiler is confused

```
    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    close(s)
```

how to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your member function:

```
close(s)
```

Function in global namespace:

```
::close(s)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the verb *Qualify*.

Comment: However `::close(s)` is invalid because `close` could also be defined as a macro; this is permitted by POSIX (which defines `close`). You need to `#undef close` before using `::close` is valid. This issue actually recently hit someone I was working with.

Comment: @R..: if close is defined as a macro then his member function name will also be affected and since C doesn't have namespaces this solution will work even then

Comment: @user1233963: No, things are more complicated if it's a function-like macro; the member function definition will almost surely fail to even parse correctly.

Comment: @R.. : C++ specifially says that all function names taken from the C library must be functions, not macro's. This may require `#ifndef __cplusplus` constructs in the appropriate headers. POSIX does not try to mandate how C++ compilers work, so that's not directly relevant. (It's a recurring source of subtle compiler bugs, though)

Answer (score 2):

Use scope resolution operator(::) for global function.

Answer (score 0):

the compiler usually change the name of functions you define to some unique function name. so if you use function overriding the compiler has its unique name for every function. This is done with the help of name mangling in C++.
You should read the concept of name mangling that can help you solve the issue.